# regular expression for substitue python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i like to substitute new string 'MEMORY247' in place of 0.0MB,2GB,0Gb...strings for this i tried below RE but it give wrong results please tell me right Regular expression for this using python

b = re.sub("\d.(\s\w+b)",'MEMORY247','0.0Mb is not enough 2GB is much 0gb more space 3.4gb')

Thanks'
Mukthar

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're trying to accomplish. In your question, can you post A) what an example string looks like BEFORE substitution, and B) the same example string AFTER substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
re.sub("\d+\.*\d*\w*", 'MEMORY247', '0.0Mb is not enough 2GB is much 0gb more space 3.4gb')
```

It means:

- \d+ find at least one digit
- .* there might be a dot
- \d* there might be more digits
- \w* there might be some characters

this regex is even better:

```
"\d+\.*\d*[kKmMgG][bB]"
```

Comment: This RE will match `3musketeers`, as well as `and1`. How about something a bit more specific?

Comment: Not fair, for the given string it will work. Who said the input is completely random?

Comment: so it match money 0.00rs treat as memory and give wrong results..please tell me exact solution for this ..

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
>>>st='0.0Mb is not enough 2GB is much 0gb more space 3.4gb'
>>>re.sub('(\d+\.*\d*((MB)|(GB)))','MEMORY247',st,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
>>>'MEMORY247 is not enough MEMORY247 is much MEMORY247 more space MEMORY247'
>>>
```

The pattern you are searching is

- a number \d+
- followed by an optional dot  .*
- followed by an optional number \d*
- followed by either GB or MB ((MB)|(GB))

to make the match case insensitive, pass re.IGNORECASE as a flag